# Trying to understand the benefit or use case of of device twins

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I am using devices like ESP32 or ESP8266 to send sensor data to Azure IoT Hub. I am productive with my setup and Azure IoT Hub serves me well.

While I use the IoT Hub, I am noticing there are so many documentation reference to the concept of device twins:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins

I read the document, but I am not understanding how Device twins can help my ESP32 projects?

How the "Device Twins" feature of IoT Hib can improve my ESP32 projects?

Comment: I think the concept is to have a JSON document (for example) in the cloud so that other devices and services can query it and obtain a result/response with shorter latency than querying the device itself.  It also frees the device from having to dedicate cycles to respond to these queries and reduces traffic to the device as well.  It's a document that would mirror your device's meta data and even provided additional information (i.e. device deployment location) so that it can easily be found and used in your ecosystem

Comment: @blurfus hits the nail on the head with that comment (and it would make a great answer). I would also note that the device twin can also serve as a configuration for the device and can be changed even when the device is offline. This way the device can always find its desired configuration when it boots up.

Comment: Thanks @MatthijsvanderVeer - I will add it as an answer and include your additional comment, if you are OK with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the concept is to have a JSON document (for example) in the cloud so that other devices and services can query it and obtain a result/response with shorter latency than querying the device itself. It also frees the device from having to dedicate cycles to respond to these queries and reduces traffic to the device as well.

Basically, it's a document that would mirror your device's meta data and even provide additional information (i.e. device deployment location) so that it can easily be found and used in your ecosystem.

In addition, [@MatthijsvanderVeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8800237/matthijs-van-der-veer) commented:

> "the device twin can also serve as a configuration for the device and
> can be changed even when the device is offline. This way the device
> can always find its desired configuration when it boots up."